# What is an elegant way to use a column of sql output for the tag of xml output within mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure that returns xml.

Sample call is

```
get_organization_user_export_data_permission_procedure
    @organizationId = '64483342-af49-4a04-b25d-ce7346cb5375' 
,   @userId = '5324B48E-B560-4345-B290-12CC72D722FA'
```

Sample output is

```
<root>
  <all>false</all>
  <analytics>false</analytics>
  <none>true</none>
</root>
```

Which is correct.

The base SQL is

```
select lower([type]) name, 
value permission,
count(permissionType) found 
from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
left join ( 
    select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
    where organizationId = '64483342-af49-4a04-b25d-ce7346cb5375'
    and userId = '5324B48E-B560-4345-B290-12CC72D722FA' ) permission
on export.value = permission.permissionType
group by [type], value
```

which returns

```
name    permission  found
none    0   1
all 1   0
analytics   2   0
```

The problem is I've hardcoded the element tag names within the stored procedure.
This is the stored procedure which shows I've got a separate subquery for each of the possible element tag names.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_organization_user_export_data_permission_procedure]
(
    @organizationId uniqueidentifier
,   @userId uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (
        select count(*) from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
        where organizationId = @organizationId
        and userId = @userId
    ) = 0 begin
        insert into [OrganizationUserDataPermission] ( id, organizationId, userId, permissionType, createDateTime )
        select newId(),@organizationId organizationId, @userId userId, 0 permissionType, getDate()
    end 

    declare @result XML

    set @result = (
        select '',  
        (
            select case true when 0 then 'false' else 'true' end 'all' from (
                select lower([type]) name, 
                value permission,
                count(permissionType) true 
                from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
                left join ( 
                    select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
                    where organizationId = @organizationId
                    and userId = @userId ) permission
                on export.value = permission.permissionType
                where value = 1
                group by [type], value
            ) [all]
        ) 'all'
        , (
            select case true when 0 then 'false' else 'true' end 'analytics' from (
                select lower([type]) name, 
                value permission,
                count(permissionType) true 
                from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
                left join ( 
                    select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
                    where organizationId = @organizationId
                    and userId = @userId ) permission
                on export.value = permission.permissionType
                where value = 2
                group by [type], value
            ) [analytics]
        ) 'analytics'
        , (
            select case true when 0 then 'false' else 'true' end 'none' from (
                select lower([type]) name, 
                value permission,
                count(permissionType) true 
                from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
                left join ( 
                    select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
                    where organizationId = @organizationId
                    and userId = @userId ) permission
                on export.value = permission.permissionType
                where value = 0
                group by [type], value
            ) [none]
        ) 'none'
        for xml path(''), root('root')
    ) 

    select @result result

END

GO
```

At the moment if another export permission where introduced I'd have to alter the stored procedure (and the view). Is there an elegant way ... by elegant I mean without using dynamic sql ... to produce the same xml results without knowing beforehand what the permissions might be?

Supporting schema.

The view ... named so that it marries to the c# code it relates to.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] AS
select 'All' [type], 1 [value]
union
select 'Analytics' [type],  2 [value]
union
select 'None' [type], 0 [value]
```

The table without foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrganizationUserDataPermission](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PermissionType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrganizationUserDataPermission] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

-- some sample data

```
insert into [OrganizationUserDataPermission] ( id, organizationId, userId, permissionType, createDateTime )
select newId(),'64483342-af49-4a04-b25d-ce7346cb5375' organizationId, '5324B48E-B560-4345-B290-12CC72D722FA' userId, 1 permissionType, getDate()
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between XML tags and permissions? Can't you store tags in a table with a link to permissions? Can you share the table and view definitions?

Comment: Added supporting schema and sample data @under

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I place this as another answer, as it follows a completely different approach:

In general it **is impossible, to define a column alias dynamically**. The element names in an XML are taken from the column names, so this applies here too.

### But

An XML is technically seen a string. Normally I would not advise to build XML on string base, but - as long as you are sure, that your element's names will never contain any forbidden characters, this is a solution, which is truly generically taken from the data given:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(name VARCHAR(100),permission INT,found BIT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('none',0,1)
,('all',1,0)
,('analytics',2,0);


SELECT CAST('<root>'
      + (
            SELECT '<' + name + '>' + CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END + '</' + name + '>'
            FROM @tbl
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
         ).value('.','varchar(max)') 
      +'</root>' AS XML)
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can tell you for sure: This is much to complicated!

One thing you could change easily, was to transfer the identical *sub-select* into one `CTE`.

But - if I understand this correctly - this can be done much easier:

You tell me

> ```
> The base SQL is
>
> select lower([type]) name, 
> value permission,
> count(permissionType) found 
> from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
> left join ( 
>     select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
>     where organizationId = '64483342-af49-4a04-b25d-ce7346cb5375'
>     and userId = '5324B48E-B560-4345-B290-12CC72D722FA' ) permission
> on export.value = permission.permissionType
> group by [type], value
> ```
>
> which returns
>
> ```
> name    permission  found
> none    0   1
> all 1   0
> analytics   2   0
> ```

Assuming, the returned values are OK, you can go with *conditional aggregation*:

A *mock-up* table to simulate your final result from above

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(name VARCHAR(100),permission INT,found BIT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('none',0,1)
,('all',1,0)
,('analytics',2,0);
```

--The query

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN(name='all') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [all]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN(name='analytics') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [analytics]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN(name='none') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [none]
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY name
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <all>false</all>
  <analytics>false</analytics>
  <none>true</none>
</root>
```

For your case this migth be this

```
WITH MyQuery aS
(
    select lower([type]) name, 
    value permission,
    count(permissionType) found 
    from [GroupExportRestrictionTypeConstants_RestrictionType_view] export
    left join ( 
        select permissionType from [OrganizationUserDataPermission] 
        where organizationId = '64483342-af49-4a04-b25d-ce7346cb5375'
        and userId = '5324B48E-B560-4345-B290-12CC72D722FA' ) permission
    on export.value = permission.permissionType
    group by [type], value  
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN(name='all') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [all]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN(name='analytics') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [analytics]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN(name='none') THEN CASE WHEN found=1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END END) AS [none]
FROM MyQuery
GROUP BY name
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root');
```

Comment: Looks simpler than mine and still has the hassle of hard coding the element names.

Comment: Your code is way more elegant than what I wrote @Shnugo :-) Thanks!

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison One question which just came into my mind: Why not use `<root><value type="all">false</value><value type="analytics">false</value><value type="none">true</true></root>`? This is much easier to create and the reading side can rely on the elements names. It is very clumsy to deal with recordsets or XMLs where the reading side does not know the columns in advance... (That's the reason why it is not possible without tricks)...

Comment: I used to write xml that way and I prefer it, however, the current xml structure is designed to be swapped out for json. The xml maps to { "all":true, "analytics":false,"none":false}. I use this in a REST #c asp server. I send in json which gets transformed to xml to go into mssql stored procedures. I return xml which gets transformed to json to be returned via the rest server. I use Newtonsoft to to the transformations. The key determinant here is the json being sent to and being returned from the REST server. That's why the xml is structured this way.